# SPA call CORS disabled api's

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors

I'm creating a SPA for personal use. I would like to display my calendar on it and a lot of other content on one page.

I have a nodejs based server that creates a react based SPA. All different react components would like to get their content from a different source and update independently from each other.

Problem: calling CORS disabled api's like google calendar will always reject requests coming from a different source.

Currently I'm creating a microservice as proxy for each component. But most components are so small they could do it inside react as well.

Any work-arounds for this? Can I spoof my origin using openvpn for example?

Comment: You can’t spoof your origin to the browser — and that’s the only place it matters what your origin is. The browser knows the actual origin where your frontend code is running, and you can’t trick a browser into thinking your code is running at some origin other than its actual origin.

Comment: The origin is the refering website, not the browser's location. Browsers allow you to read origin but not to change it (for security purpose). I tried to reach some rss feed using javascript xmlhttprequest but also faced the CORS problem. So you will need these microservices however you create them. I havent tried to use workers. It is up to the ressource provider to decide what origins are allowed.

Comment: Serverside directive to manage it ithttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @Tuckbros With "workers" you mean microservices that proxy the the request, right?

Comment: Yes, only client-side javascript. With the ability of being "shared" I thought there was a way. But it seems not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker Note: If SharedWorker can be accessed from several browsing contexts, all those browsing contexts must share the exact same origin (same protocol, host and port).

Comment: I might want to checkout those workers, seems new to me. I refer to my proxy as a new python/flask server with cors disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `proxy`, then you do not have to concern about `cors` issue since proxy will make request instead.

you may work with `CRA v2` via `yarn add create react-app project-name`

and `CRA v2 webpack dev server` supports `proxy`.

inside of package.json file, add `"proxy": "https://domainName.com"`

and call API whatever you want.

for example, if you want to make API call to `https://domaiName.com/something`

just make request to `'/something'` since we already fixed proxy url

if you are not using CRA, you can make proxy on your own but I strongly recommend you to using it and customize your project

hope it helps.

Comment: Don't think it applies to me. What if I want to call two different api's? e.g. google calendar and gmail? Can't do that if all calls go to one domain, right?

Comment: @hasdrubal that would not be a problem. using http-proxy-middleware, read https://medium.com/@Pavan_/set-up-proxy-to-work-with-multiple-apis-in-create-react-app-be595a713eb2 and also, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1790 would help.

Comment: Then I think this is the easiest solution offered so far.